# Age Group Query but different kind of grouping

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the following query:

```
Declare @StartDate datetime
Set @StartDate = '2016-12-11 14:53:16.770'

select 
DrugName,
AgeGroup,
count(*) as Clients
from
(select 
D.DrugName,
case
when datediff(d,DOB,@StartDate) / 365.25 > 64 then '65 & over'
when datediff(d,DOB,@StartDate) / 365.25 > 54 then '55-64'
when datediff(d,DOB,@StartDate) / 365.25 > 44 then '45-54'
when datediff(d,DOB,@StartDate) / 365.25 > 34 then '35-44'
when datediff(d,DOB,@StartDate) / 365.25 > 24 then '25-34'
when datediff(d,DOB,@StartDate) / 365.25 > 18 then '19-24'
when datediff(d,DOB,@StartDate) / 365.25 > 12 then '13-18'
when datediff(d,DOB,@StartDate) / 365.25 > 0 then 'Below 12'
  end as AgeGroup
from Client C
Inner Join Visit V on C.ClientID = V.ClientID
Inner Join Drug D on V.DrugID = D.DrugID
) a
group by DrugName,AgeGroup
order by DrugName,AgeGroup
```

and it returns the correct results grouping by all the DrugNames and showing the counts properly.

I have this table also:

```
select * from AgeGroup
```

that contains the following data:

```
AgeGroupID  AgeGroup
1          65 & over
2          55-64
3          45-54
4          35-44
5          25-34
6          19-24
7          13-18
8          Below 12
```

The problem I have is that I'm not sure how to show all Age Groups for each Drug Name.

At the moment for Cocaine I get the following result in my above query:

```
Cocaine 19-24       1
Cocaine 25-34       10
Cocaine 35-44       15
Cocaine 45-54       20
Cocaine 55-64       25
Cocaine 65 & over   30
```

but I want to get:

```
Cocaine Below 12    0
Cocaine 13-18       0
Cocaine 19-24       1
Cocaine 25-34       10
Cocaine 35-44       15
Cocaine 45-54       20
Cocaine 55-64       25
Cocaine 65 & over   30
```

and likewise for all other drugs that show in the result set that have a missing age range. How could I do that?

Comment: Cross Join the both if you want all combinations

Comment: Create a `age_range` table that'll have all your ranges, cross join with `distinct drugtypes` and make a left join of it with your above result.

Comment: the problem is that you do not have every age group represented for each of your drugs.  So you need an age group table(psuedo table) and a distinct select of drugs then cross join the 2 and LEFT JOIN back to the table.  Also note that your AGE calculation does NOT take into account when someone's birthday has not yet occurred in a year and 365.25 will be off some years and not others

Comment: Thanks @Matt - how would you suggest I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Declare @StartDate datetime
Set @StartDate = '2016-12-11 14:53:16.770'

;WITH cteAgeGroups AS (
    SELECT *
    FROM
       (VALUES (65,1000,'65 & over'),(55,64,'55-64'),(45,54,'45-54')
       ,(35,44,'35-44'),(25,34,'25-34'),(19,24,'19-24'),(13,18,'13-18')
       ,(0,12,'12 & Below')) t(StartRange,EndRange,AgeGroup)
)

SELECT
    a.AgeGroup
    ,d.DrugName
    ,COUNT(c.ClientId) as Clients
FROM
    cteAgeGroups a
    CROSS JOIN Drug d
    LEFT JOIN Visit v
    ON d.DrugId = v.DrugId
    LEFT JOIN Client c
    ON v.ClientId = c.ClientId
    AND (
       CASE
          WHEN
             (DATEADD(year,DATEDIFF(year, c.[DOB]  ,@StartDate) , c.[DOB]) > @StartDate)
          THEN DATEDIFF(year, c.[DOB]  ,@StartDate) -1
          ELSE DATEDIFF(year, c.[DOB]  ,@StartDate)
       END) BETWEEN a.StartRange AND a.EndRange
GROUP BY
    a.AgeGroup
    ,d.DrugName
```

Comment: Thanks for the clear great response Matt - worked a treat :)

Comment: @James you are welcome.  The trick in this type of scenarios is you have to use cross joins to create all possible combinations so that you can figure out which combinations you do not know.

Comment: makes sense. Thanks.  I really like the AgeGroup idea so it doesn't require a hard-coded case statement. I'm trying to incorporate that into another query actually. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

If you need all combinations of both tables, you need to use `CROSS JOIN`

```
    SELECT * FROM DRUGS
     CROSS JOIN  AGEGROUP
```

Comment: You said that you have separate table for AgeGroup. And in the query you are calculating age group by using DOB.

Comment: You might be fit with  @matt  answer below